# How can I handle previous header value after pollenrich?

Tags: apache-camel

all.

I have some route of camel.
My scenario is below.

1. file size checking on remote server

2. store the file size on header

3. get the file by sftp through pollenrich

4. compare the size of downloaded file with the size of original header value

5. if there is different, retry the download

I know that the value of old header is disappear after pollenrich.
Is there any anything to meet my scenario I can do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @burki has said, a custom aggregation strategy will work. Here is an example propagating a message header and an exchange parameter from the initial exchange to the new exchange.

```
.pollEnrich()
.simple("myUrl?param=${header.myUrlParameter}")
.aggregationStrategy( new AggregationStrategy() { 
    public Exchange aggregate( Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange ) 
    { 
        newExchange.getIn().setHeader( "MyHeader", oldExchange.getIn().getHeader( "MyHeader" ) );
        newExchange.setProperty( "MyProperty", oldExchange.getProperty( "MyProperty" ) );
        return newExchange; 
    } } )
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to **use pollEnrich with an AggregationStrategy** that **implements how the original message and the enrich message are merged**.

I guess you are getting the merge result of the default strategy because you don't reference a strategy.

Have a look at the first example of the [Enrich Options](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/content-enricher.html#ContentEnricher-EnrichOptions) in the Camel docs (section "Using the Fluent Builders").

I think you should be able to integrate headers from the original message into the merged message so that they are still available after the enrich step.